# why must use "npx" to cek version program on npm global?

Tags: vue.js, npm, npx

I have a problem when I use the npm command. why when I use the npm command to check the version program must use npx? it does not work when I don't use npx
For example when I use Vue --version to check cli vue version

```
vue --version
bash: vue: command not found

npx vue --version
@vue/cli 5.0.6
```

[npx error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kXMp.png)

Comment: Because vue is installed locally on your project, but is not available globally. If it's installed globally but it cant find it, it means there is something wrong with your $PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your PATH variable with this command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/denis/.npm-global/bin
```

Updating `Node/NPM` might help too.